# How to remove Ubuntu in favor of Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bootable-media

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop and it is the only OS that I have in it.

**My goal** is to get rid of Ubuntu and substitute it with Windows 10.

**Here are my questions**:

- Is it possible to download the Windows 10 iso file directly form the windows website (https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/software-download/windows10ISO)?
- I believe the answer to my previous question is yes; however I don't understand why it is free; am I going to be asked to pay something afterwards? will I need a product key?
- If I make a bootable usb flash drive having Windows 10 in it, will I be able to completely overwrite Ubuntu?

**My final idea** is to have a Pc with only Windows 10 in it and nothing else. It should look like most possibly to a Pc that came with Windows OS pre-installed in it. For what concerns the partitions I would like them to be the least number possible (I believe they should be just 2: System Reserved and C)

**My final doubt**: are there other problems or drawbacks that I should keep in mind while doing these procedure?

Possible idea: I have another Pc with Windows 7; can I download Windows 10 from it, make a bootable usb and launch it in my Pc?

Comment: "will I need a product key?" - If you don't have a previous version of Windows installed then Windows 10 isn't free, it cost money, just like every other version of Windows does.  Windows 10 isn't free, as in air, only eligible existing users of Windows can upgrade to Windows 10 for free until July 29th 2016.  After July 29th 2016 it will cost money for everyone.

Comment: note that Microsoft now allows you to install Windows 10 and type in the Product key from your Windows 7 computer to activate it. So you do not need to upgrade the windows 7 first. Legally, you would need to stop using the windows 7 machine after that. (*can't have your cake and eat it*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes, you need a product key
3. Yes

You could use your windows 7 machine to do it, or you can make it from Ubuntu using [winusb](http://en.congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html) (I don't know if this is compatible with Windows 10 to be honest, it's somewhat out of date now. You may be better off using the Microsoft tool from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) on your Windows machine)

Only real consideration is to make sure you've got all the data you need backed up, as when you install Windows it'll want to trash your EXT and SWAP partitions. When you run through the installer you can tell it to delete the 'unknown partitions' and it can automatically use the free space to create the partitions it needs.

Otherwise, install and after a quick hunt for drivers and a valid product key, you can do that without a problem.

Comment: what are the drawbacks of not inserting the product key during installation?

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried it, but I have seen a few different reports looking online. One is that you CAN skip entering a product key on installation, you won't be able to use personalisation settings, and you only receive updates for a year, with a nag prompt that it's not activated. Other sources state you can use it for 30 days before it will stop working, with the ability to 'rearm' it through the command line to extend your trial up to 240 days. How true this is, I don't know, I haven't tried it I'm afraid.

Comment: [Source 1](http://betanews.com/2015/07/22/youll-be-able-to-try-windows-10-for-free-without-a-product-key/) and
[Source 2](http://www.top-password.com/blog/extend-windows-trial-period-from-30-to-120-days/)